# UIScrollView with images

Tags: objective-c, image, ios, uiscrollview

Hey, So I have 5 images I want in a UIScrollView the user can scroll thru. But i want the scrollview to stop at every image so you'll have to scroll again to see the next image.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

`myuiscrollview.pagingEnabled = YES;`

for a simple way which means that the scroll view will stop on multiple of its relevant axis bounds.

But if you want to get a bit cleverer you can use the delegate method

`- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView`

and use the `contentOffset` property to stop at the point you want

Comment: I have analyzed the suggestion and short of coding an example, I think that is should work.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the `pagingEnabled` property: [UIScrollView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html)